# How does the computer calculate or store Diffie-Hellman values?

Tags: php, encryption, diffie-hellman

So usually the Diffie-Hellman key is 2048 bits as I understand but my computer can barely calculate a 10 digit number. What are some common numbers in Diffie-Hellman?

Here is my code that's suuuper slow:

```php
    $gen = 77;
    $mod = 517165;
    
    $saltA = 1233217;
    $saltB = 5173123;
    
    $calculatedSecretKeyA = gmp_mod(gmp_pow($gen, $saltA), $mod);
    
    $calculatedSecretKeyB = gmp_mod(gmp_pow($gen, $saltB), $mod);

    $calcKeyA = gmp_mod(gmp_pow($calculatedSecretKeyB, $saltA), $mod);
    echo $calculatedSecretKeyB . "^" . $saltA . "" . " mod " . $mod . " = " . $calcKeyA;
    
    
    $calcKeyB = gmp_mod(gmp_pow($calculatedSecretKeyA, $saltB), $mod);
    echo $calculatedSecretKeyA . "^" . $saltB . "" . " mod " . $mod . " = " . $calcKeyB;
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to implement Diffie Helmann in PHP, and I see you are using GMP to handle the large integers.  A few years ago, I had a need to do the same thing.  See https://github.com/meixler/ecdh-php.

Comment: @mti2935: Your code seems to do ECDH, Lukas' seems to be trying to do mod p DH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [gmp_powm](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-powm.php)

> gmp_powm ( GMP|int|string $num , GMP|int|string $exponent , GMP|int|string $modulus ) : GMP

for the below lines.

```php
$calculatedSecretKeyA = gmp_powm($gen, $saltA, $mod);

$calculatedSecretKeyB = gmp_powm($gen, $saltB, $mod);

$calcKeyA = gmp_powm($calculatedSecretKeyB, $saltA, $mod);
    
$calcKeyB = gmp_powm($calculatedSecretKeyA, $saltB, $mod);
```

It uses the [modular form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) of [square-and-multiply technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). The intermediate values will never exceed `mod^2`. Also, it has `O(log n)` complexity.